# Whether the directory set by "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" will find its subdirectory?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I want to run a c++ code with lib.so and set the "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/apollo/bazel-bin" but the lib.so is in "/apollo/bazel-bin/python", then I got the error can't find the lib.so.
Whether the directory set by "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" will find its subdirectory? I have some lib.so in "/apollo/bazel-bin/a" "/apollo/bazel-bin/b" and "/apollo/bazel-bin/c", I don't want to set 3 dir but "/apollo/bazel-bin/"?

Comment: You can set multiple paths separated by `;` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. And no, subdirectories aren't searched automatically.

Comment: Link with options `-L/apollo/bazel-bin/lib -Wl,-R,/apollo/bazel-bin/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags`. The RUNPATH will be part of the exectuable, and you won't have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Thx, I will try this method

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, elements of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are not searched recursively.